# Why was Emil Blonsky wearing a U.S. Army uniform?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk-2008

In *The Incredible Hulk* (2008), Emil Blonsky was a Royal Marine on loan to the U.S. Army SOC. But he appears in the film wearing the same uniform as Gen. Ross:
[image: Screen grab of Captain Emil Blonsky and General Ross wearing identical green U.S. Army service uniforms]

They have the same crossed rifles insignias and everything. Is there an explanation for this, or is it just a goof?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's just a goof. Note also that the uniforms are wrong. The design was phased out before the film came out, the insignia are worn on the wrong sides and Blonsky's bars don't correspond with any known US or UK decoration

Comment: @Valorum That was my hunch, but I don't know much about military customs/protocols or the background of the character in the comics, so figured I'd ask. From a military perspective, it's also probably a bit silly to use a top-secret super soldier serum on a foreign soldier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Emil Blonski was an *Exchange Officer* - that is an officer seconded to (on temporary duty to) US Army - it would be possible.

An Exchange Officer is considered subordinate to the chain of command of the unit he's attached to and subject to its regulations. In practice it's a somewhat fuzzy area (regulations on the length and width of the moustache are quite famous in recent years).

There were - and still are - situations like this, and while normally any exchange officer is allowed to wear his own military's uniform (and most probably he would not have it any other way), there might be situations when changing uniforms might be in order. Like covert op when anybody would ask what uniform is this and drawing more attention than necessary.

As for the actual uniforms, they are indeed a hash and highly non-regulation.